# Python Regex for German tax numbers

Tags: python, regex

I need help to complete my regex for German tax numbers. The format of these numbers depend on the state. I can match almost all states. The only states left are Hessen and Bremen. The problem is, that they are very similar to other numbers (like phone numbers). I have a complete example in my [demo](https://regex101.com/r/e94r4Y/5).

Maybe you can help me, to match all relevant numbers.

This is my regex:

```
(?:\d{3}\s?/\s?\d{3}\s?/\s?\d{5})|(?:\d{2}\s?/\s?\d{3}\s?/\s?\d{5})|(?:\d{3}\s?/\s?\d{4}\s?/\s?\d{4})|(?:\d{5}\s?/\s?\d{5}\b)|(\d{11})|(\d{10})
```

These are the critical patterns which are left in order to complete the regex for all states:

```
Hessen: 02581580201
025 815 80201

Bremen: 7581508152
75 815 08152
```

Comment: You could omit `(\d{11})|(\d{10})` at the end right? Or should `02581580201` and `025 815 80201` match?

Comment: If I remove the last part of my regex ``|(\d{11})|(\d{10})``, it still doens't match the numbers for the states Hessen and Bremen

Comment: For those values, you could match either `/` between optional whitespace chars, or a single whitspace char `\b(?:\d{3}(?:\s?/\s?|\s)\d{3}(?:\s?/\s?|\s)\d{5}|\d{2}(?:\s?/\s?|\s)\d{3}(?:\s?/\s?|\s)\d{5}|\d{3}\s?/\s?\d{4}\s?/\s?\d{4}|\d{5}(?:\s?/\s?|\s)\d{5}|\d{10,11})\b` and then put them in 1 alternation surrounded by word boundaries. https://regex101.com/r/RaICQa/1

Comment: plz show me acutal input and its expected output.

Comment: @PParker There are a few instances where you are essentially using `|` to act as a quantifier e.g. `(\d{11})|(\d{10})`. With quantifiers this would look like `\d{10,11}`. Use quantifiers or not, it's up to you but I thought it pertinent to point out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match either `/` between optional whitespace chars, or match a whitespace chars using `(?:\s?/\s?|\s)`

The part at the end can be shortened to `\d{10,11}`.

The first 2 parts can be shortened to `d{2,3}\s?/\s?\d{3}\s?/\s?\d{5}`

```
\b(?:\d{2,3}(?:\s?/\s?|\s)\d{3}(?:\s?/\s?|\s)\d{5}|\d{3}(?:\s?/\s?|\s)\d{4}(?:\s?/\s?|\s)\d{4}|\d{5}(?:\s?/\s?|\s)\d{5}|\d{10,11})\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent the match being part of a larger word
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\d{2,3}(?:\s?/\s?|\s)\d{3}(?:\s?/\s?|\s)\d{5}` Match 2-3 digits, then 3 digits and 5 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{3}(?:\s?/\s?|\s)\d{4}(?:\s?/\s?|\s)\d{4}` Match 3 digits, 4 digits and 4 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{5}(?:\s?/\s?|\s)\d{5}|\d{10,11}` Match 5 digits, 5 digits and either 10 or 11 digits
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G61ORh/1)

If the parts between the digits should match up, you could also use a capturing group with a backreference to match the same in the second part what has already been captured in the first part.